# Displaying a score from highest to lowest

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsarray

My score is displaying just not in the correct order. I've been trying to make a method that uses `@selector(compare:)` but have had no such luck.

Here's the code I'm working with and I'm wanting to display it from highest to lowest. I'm also wanting to have it so that if you load the app for the first time it creates an empty array so that if the user tries to look at the highscores it doesn't crash the app.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *scoresListPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"scores.plist"];

scoresList = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:scoresListPath] retain];

if (scoresList == nil) {
    scoresList = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
}
```

and

```
- (void)addHighScore:(float)finalScore {
    [scoresList addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:finalScore]];

    [scoresList sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *scoresListPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"scores.plist"];
    [scoresList writeToFile:scoresListPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: objective C this is for an iPhone app

Comment: Can you post the `compare:` method you are using? The code seems correct to me. What do you mean when you say "I've been trying to make a method that uses @selector(compare:) but have had no such luck"?

Comment: can you edit this to provide a little more context? It would help you to receive more answers.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the replies. I've got it so it creates an empty array and my game no longer has the crash issue. I still haven't solved my other problem on creating a compare method that works. I was completely on the wrong track before and I was wondering if someone could help me out and get me started. What it does is displays my scores from lowest to highest and I want them to display from highest to lowest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is failing is because `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` returns an immutable array even though it is called on `NSMutableArray`. You should make a mutable copy of the array that you read of the file like this,

```
scoresList = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:scoresListPath] mutableCopy];
```

This will give you an `NSMutableArray` object which can be added to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about lowest but,you can use GKLeaderBoardViewController class for counting Highest Score.For more details I suggested you to read below link.Thanks

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboardViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html